# JUNIT Android. Links to the activity

Tags: android, junit

Sorry for my english, I'm from Russia. Testing a button, when pressed to appear activity. How to get a link to this activity?

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_test.html for details how to test your activities

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
   Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,yourcalss.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```